# Adding Guava's library to NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, guava

I have some issues based on adding Guava's StopWatch in NetBeans.

I need to import the stopwatch class: import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;, but this class isn't included among the different opportunities after "base.". Other classes such as CharMatcher is included though. I have added both guava-r09.jar and guava-r09-gwt.jar files.[image]

Comment: Try a newer version of guava.  Stopwatch isn't in r09.

Comment: The latest version of Guava is 16.0.1, and I'd strongly recommend using that. r09 is almost 3 years old at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stopwatch` was added in 10.0, as mentionned in the [Javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html): look for the `@since`/Since.